Find points in one polygon not overlapping with another polygon
I have a polygon and a circle on a map. The polygon has no holes, while the circle is the minimum bounding circle for this polygon, such that it is the smallest circle containing all coordinates from the polygon.
I have the vertices of each of these two shapes. I would like to find a way to determine the shape of the non-overlapping polygon i.e. the points in the circle that aren't in the polygon.
Is there an efficient way to do this?
Thanks,
Mike
